# How to do apt-get update and upgrade during preseed?

Tags: upgrade, updates, preseed

Right now, I'm using a bash script using packer to run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y`. I'd like to do this in the preseed phase if possible. Is there a way to do this?

I thought this `d-i` command would work, but I don't want it to do a `sudo apt dist-upgrade`. Could someone explain these values?

```
# Whether to upgrade packages after debootstrap.
# Allowed values: none, safe-upgrade, full-upgrade
#d-i pkgsel/upgrade select none
```

Is there any way to do a package upgrade in the packing process using the preseed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preseed:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
  in-target rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists ; \
  in-target apt-get update ; \
  in-target apt-get -y upgrade ; \
  in-target apt-get -y dist-upgrade ; \
  in-target apt-get -y autoremove ; \
  in-target apt-get autoclean ; \
  in-target apt-get clean
```

- this includes a dist-upgrade but that's easily removed.

Ubuntu has kickstart with preseed support and kickstart can do it like this by using a "%post" option:

```
%post --interpreter=/bin/bash
#!/bin/bash 
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

---

[Kickstart](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KickstartCompatibility#Integration_with_Preseed) can use preseed:

> Integration with Preseed
>
> While Debian's preseed can fully automate the entire Ubuntu installation, the official Red Hat kickstart language cannot. For this reason, Ubuntu kickstart includes a special command preseed which allows using preseed options inside a Kickstart file. Here is an example of mixing kickstart syntax with some preseed syntax.
>
> ```
> # Kickstart syntax: Configure authentication 
> auth --useshadow --enablemd5
> ```
>
> # Ubuntu Kickstart Syntax: Use an option only available via preseed to tell
>
> # Ubuntu's installer not to make a non-root user during installation
>
> ```
> preseed passwd/make-user boolean false
> ```
>
> # Ubuntu Kickstart Syntax: Check "Install any security updates automatically"
>
> ```
> preseed pkgsel/update-policy select unattended-upgrades
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Ah never used kickstart but I'll look more into that. Any idea what the `full-upgrade` option does?

Comment: Ha found a preseed version :) try the edit. From what I read full-upgrade option does not work :P

Comment: Why do you need to remove `/var/lib/apt/lists`?